# IE11 empty page using Angular 7

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

I'm testing my personal website from host. It works fine with chrome, safari, firefox, almost fine with edge, and not at all with IE11.
The page displayed is index.html, the scripts don't load and so, my page is desperately white.
What direction should I look at?

Below is the source code after loading, it just renders the index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>xxxxx</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300, 400|Permanent+Marker|Fredoka+One" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.e51f265321605de0a6b8.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.46532d96d3286697c138.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.a5dd35324ddfd942bef1.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.d7a4eeb20e2af3af291c.js"></script>
</body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

polyfills.ts

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
 import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.


/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
```

Comment: TY for your answer, this is my first angular deployment. polyfills.ts was the solution.

Answer (score 2):

for angular8 user. please refer to below. :

polyfills.ts :remove number after es

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
    import 'core-js/es/symbol';
    import 'core-js/es/object';
    import 'core-js/es/function';
    import 'core-js/es/parse-int';
    import 'core-js/es/parse-float';
    import 'core-js/es/number';
    import 'core-js/es/math';
    import 'core-js/es/string';
    import 'core-js/es/date';
    import 'core-js/es/array';
    import 'core-js/es/regexp';
    import 'core-js/es/map';
    import 'core-js/es/weak-map';
    import 'core-js/es/set';
    import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

    /** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
    import 'core-js/es/reflect';
```

tsconfig.json

```
"target": "es5", // "target": "es2015",
```

browerslist

```
IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, **remove 'not'.**
```

credit :https://dev.to/paulinhapenedo/angular-8-and-ie-11-1ed2

Answer (score 0):

You should look if you have the good `polyfills`.

And do you have errors in your console ?

Answer (score 0):

Besides activating polyfills I personally also had to unchecked "Display intranet sites in Compatibilty View" under "Compatibility View Settings" in a productive environment. 
Maybe this applies to you, too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running angular 8 application in windows 10 with IE11.

I tried many solutions from stackoverflow. But didn't worked anything. then i tried same solutions separately, then i got to one conclusion.

This is my final solution. i don't for howmany people it will work. but for me it worked.

**1. tsconfig.json**

```
   "target": "es2015"
```

changed to

```
"target": "es5"
```

**2. Stop your applications and start again. this Mandatory.**

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution (2021):

1. go to `tsconfig.json` and change the `target` to `es5`

```
"target": "es5"
```

2. go to `browserslist` and remove `not` as description in the file to support IE 9 -11

```
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
not IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.
```

to

```
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.
```

3. add `meta` tag to index.html file

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```