# How do I support Internet Explorer in an Angular 8 application?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, polyfills, angular8

When I generate a project with Angular CLI (8.0.0), I run `ng serve`, open the application up in Internet Explorer and I am presented with a blank screen.

I had a look at the `polyfills.ts` files and I uncommented the following lines:

```
    import 'classlist.js';
    import 'web-animations-js';
```

I've also removed all core.js imports as Angular 8 supports core.js 3.0 directly.

I've also ran `npm i`.

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.0.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.0.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  }
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

browserlists:

```
# This file is used by the build system to adjust CSS and JS output to support the specified browsers below.
# For additional information regarding the format and rule options, please see:
# https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#queries

# You can see what browsers were selected by your queries by running:
#   npx browserslist

> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.
```

**EDIT 2:**

The console in Internet Explorer (11) shows the following errors:

polyfills.js:
`Syntax error (3168, 5)`
(line 3168 beginning) -> `class Zone {`

vendor.js:
`Syntax error (156, 1)`
(line 156 beginning) -> `class PlatformLocation {`

main.ts:
`Syntax error (95, 20)`
(points to the AppComponent)

What else do I need to do?

Comment: In browserslist, replace `not IE 9-11` by `IE 9-11`

Comment: EDIT: The screen still remains blank and produces 3 syntax errors in ```polyfills.js```, ```vendor.js``` and ```main.js``` @JBNizet

Comment: I understand - I've updated the question. @JBNizet

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14455

Answer (score 106, accepted):

According to [this issue reply](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14455)

You need to follow the following steps

1. **Create a new tsconfig** `tsconfig.es5.json` next to tsconfig.json with the below contents

```
{
 "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
 "compilerOptions": {
     "target": "es5" 
  }
}
```

2. In `angular.json`
   Under `projects:yourAppName:architect:build:configurations`, add

```
"es5": {
      "tsConfig": "./tsconfig.es5.json"
    }
```

and `projects:yourAppName:architect:serve:configurations` add

```
    "es5": {
      "browserTarget": "yourAppName:build:es5"
    }
```

Remember to change *yourAppName* in ***app:build:es5*** to *yourAppName*!

full path shown below

```
"build": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
  "options": {
      ...
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
        ...
    },
    "es5": {
      "tsConfig": "./tsconfig.es5.json"
    }
  }
},
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "options": {
      ...
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
     ...
    },
    "es5": {
      "browserTarget": "yourAppName:build:es5"
    }
  }
},
```

3. Run the serve with this configuration using the below command.

```
ng serve --configuration es5
```

Comment: If ```ng serve --configuration es5``` doesn't work, try ```ng s -c=es5```

Comment: I had to provide the the tsconfig path like so: `"tsConfig": "src/tsconfig-es5.app.json"`

Comment: do i need to this if i only use ng build ?

Comment: this is not working when i do with ng build.How work my app in development build on ie11?

Comment: If I have `projects > projectName > architect > build > options > styles` in `angular.json`, do I need to copy it to `projects > projectName > architect > build > configurations > es5`? The thing is my application loads, but styles are missing.

Comment: This solution is not working for me. getting "Invalid character" from vendor.js in IE11 browser console. have tried all the solutions that are in this page. struggling from 3 days. any help would be much appreciated. for more about issue description and project details  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64386606/angular-8-is-not-loading-in-ie-11-browser.

Comment: for production should i put my production config into es5 config file?

Answer (score 31):

Go to "tsconfig.json" and use target: **"es5"** instead of **"target": "es2015",**

target which is inside compileOnSave\compilerOptions

Comment: this disables the "differential loading" feature of angular. So the bundle size at the end (which the browsers download) is "always (independent of browser)" bigger than needed.

Comment: This solution is not working for me. getting "Invalid character" from vendor.js in IE11 browser console. have tried all the solutions that are in this page. struggling from 3 days. any help would be much appreciated. for more about issue description and project details stackoverflow.com/questions/64386606/

Answer (score 12):

***------Simple and Easy Way***

You need to change 2 files, `polyfills.ts` and `tsconfig.json` respectively.

Just add **Browser Polyfills** in `polyfills.ts`

```
/***************************************************************************************************
* BROWSER POLYFILLS
*/
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/promise';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

and in `tsconfig.json` **change "target" to es5** like this

```
 "target": "es5",
```

instead of

`"target": "es2015",`

Comment: Please note that: `core-js/es6/*` does not work instead use `core-js/es/*`. just change `es6` to `es`.

Comment: This solution is not working for me. getting "Invalid character" from vendor.js in IE11 browser console. have tried all the solutions that are in this page. struggling from 3 days. any help would be much appreciated. for more about issue description and project details stackoverflow.com/questions/64386606/

Comment: @Raju, please check first in incongito mode, second can you delete your node_module and npm cache clean -f then npm install. hope that will help you

Answer (score 7):

Note: my original reply was from Reddit (https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/buup6a/)

Check your tsconfig.json
While upgrading to Angular 8, the target changed to es2015 for me, so with ng serve I encountered many many problems. While compiling, the dist folder had both es5 and es2015 versions.

Basically, compiling for production will create both versions for new and older browsers like IE11

To test IE11 on development environment, I created a dev environment in angular.json where I specified a copy of tsconfig which I called tsconfig.dev.json where the target is set to es5. Run ng s -c=dev and voilá!

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I found a relevant issue in the angular-cli GitHub repository that mentions what Jie Lin has said: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14455 It's quite annoying how this isn't documented anywhere

Comment: This solution is not working for me. getting "Invalid character" from vendor.js in IE11 browser console. have tried all the solutions that are in this page. struggling from 3 days. any help would be much appreciated. for more about issue description and project details stackoverflow.com/questions/64386606/

Answer (score 6):

To support IE fully we had to pull in a special set of polyfills from the [mdn-polyfills](https://github.com/msn0/mdn-polyfills#readme) library.

To install them use

```
npm i -s mdn-polyfills
```

next add them to the polyfills.ts file like this

```
import 'mdn-polyfills/Object.assign';
import 'mdn-polyfills/Object.create';
import 'mdn-polyfills/Object.entries';
import 'mdn-polyfills/Array.from';
import 'mdn-polyfills/Array.of';
import 'mdn-polyfills/Array.prototype.find';
import 'mdn-polyfills/Array.prototype.forEach';
import 'mdn-polyfills/Array.prototype.filter';
import 'mdn-polyfills/Array.prototype.findIndex';
import 'mdn-polyfills/Array.prototype.includes';
import 'mdn-polyfills/String.prototype.includes';
import 'mdn-polyfills/String.prototype.repeat';
import 'mdn-polyfills/String.prototype.startsWith';
import 'mdn-polyfills/String.prototype.endsWith';
import 'mdn-polyfills/String.prototype.padStart';
import 'mdn-polyfills/String.prototype.padEnd';
import 'mdn-polyfills/Function.prototype.bind';
import 'mdn-polyfills/NodeList.prototype.forEach';
import 'mdn-polyfills/Element.prototype.closest';
import 'mdn-polyfills/Element.prototype.matches';
import 'mdn-polyfills/MouseEvent';
import 'mdn-polyfills/CustomEvent';
```

after this you should stop experiencing many of the issues in IE.

Comment: Can you please explain what was the reason you had to install mdn-polyfills?

Comment: For Angular 8 specifically, importing MDN polyfills will not fix the problem.

Comment: Ran into a problem with IE 11 not loading my app after updating to Angular 8 and I noticed an `Object.entries` error in my console.  Followed the instructions here and it solved my problem.

Comment: @doubleya The ES 2015 features should be supported out of the box with differential loading in Angular 8. You only need to add polyfills for the ES2017 features like Object.values and Object.entries. Instead of the mdn-polyfills, you can also `import 'core-js/es/object/values'` and `import 'core-js/es/object/entries'`.

Answer (score 4):

I Just want to add something that was useful to me:

1. Read this article from the Official Angular Documentation: https://angular.io/guide/browser-support
2. Another article to help you in your process: https://dev.to/paulinhapenedo/angular-8-and-ie-11-1ed2
3. For me the best article that helped me to understand everything, even the two previous: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-and-internet-explorer-a6e4b5a5dae1

In short, if you don't want to read any more I have taken the following steps:

- Un-comment some imports in the polyfill.ts file.

  import 'classlist.js';

  import 'web-animations-js';
- Install a couple of npm packages.

> npm install --save classlist.js
> npm install --save web-animations-js

- Modify the browserslist file. At the end of the file look for this line:

  not IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.

**Please remove *'not'* word.**

Additionaly just add Browser Polyfills in polyfills.ts

```
/***************************************************************************************************
* BROWSER POLYFILLS
*/
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es/symbol';
// import 'core-js/es/promise';
import 'core-js/es/object';
import 'core-js/es/function';
import 'core-js/es/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es/number';
import 'core-js/es/math';
import 'core-js/es/string';
import 'core-js/es/date';
import 'core-js/es/array';
import 'core-js/es/regexp';
import 'core-js/es/map';
import 'core-js/es/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es/set';
```

and in `tsconfig.json` change "target" to **es5** like this

> "target": "es5",

instead of

> "target": "es2015",

Run:

> ng serve --open

I hope it can help you :)

Answer (score 2):

Set `target` to "es5", set up your `browserslist`, that should be enough.

Read more about the topic here: https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2019/05/29/angular-cli-8.0/

Comment: This solution is not working for me. getting "Invalid character" from vendor.js in IE11 browser console. have tried all the solutions that are in this page. struggling from 3 days. any help would be much appreciated. for more about issue description and project details stackoverflow.com/questions/64386606/

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue and resolved with the two below fix. You might have come across many post mentioning about polyfill but that is not the only reason for IE not working as expected.

Solution

Add a property  **"es5BrowserSupport": true** in angular.json file. The path is shown in image.
[image]

Now, change your **target** property to "**es5**" in tsconfig.json file

[image]

Complete explanation can be found [here](https://karthiktechblog.com/angular/how-to-fix-your-angular-app-to-make-it-work-in-ie11)

By applying these two fix, IE will start working in local (debugging) and in production.

Comment: This worked for me using the Visual Studio .NET Core 3 template - just changing the target to "es5" did it - though I'm using it for a pretty low functionlity POC

Comment: This solution is not working for me. getting "Invalid character" from vendor.js in IE11 browser console. have tried all the solutions that are in this page. struggling from 3 days. any help would be much appreciated. for more about issue description and project details stackoverflow.com/questions/64386606/

Answer (score 1):

This really bothered me so I wrote a [nodeJs script](https://github.com/ChrisMeeusen/ng-ie-serve) that will enable the "workaround" defined here: [ng github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14455#issuecomment-493739768)

Being an enterprise dev that turns out tons of angular apps its not ok to do development locally against chrome and firefox only.  Anyone that's done web dev for more than a minute knows that just because it looks cool in chrome doesn't mean IE will be happy.  OK rant over just install the script and serve it in IE every now and then and check your app in IE locally before pushing  to dev.

Comment: This is great! Doesn't work in an NX workspace as the app with `browserslist`and `tsconfig.*` is in `apps/app-name` while `angular.json` is in the workspace root. Ran this in the app's folder and still saved some time having to manually edit only `angular.json`. So thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very cool Angular new feature called **differential-loading**

```
<script src=“runtime-es2015.858f8dd898b75fe86926.js” type=“module”></script>
<script src=“polyfills-es2015.e954256595c973372414.js” type=“module”></script>
<script src=“runtime-es5.741402d1d47331ce975c.js” nomodule></script>
<script src=“polyfills-es5.405730e5ac8f727bd7d7.js” nomodule></script>
<script src=“main-es2015.63808232910db02f6170.js” type=“module”></script>
<script src=“main-es5.2cc74ace5dd8b3ac2622.js” nomodule></script>
```

If you see above index.html from build folder, each js has two versions:

- One is es2015 with `type="module"`attribute for modern browsers
- Another one is es5 version with `nomodule` attribute for lagency browsers.

Therefore, Angular cli will gracefully generate it on prod. But if you want to run `ng serve` from local, then you have to manually make sure `ng serve` is running from a tsconfig file that has `target: es5`

Answer (score 1):

You just need three changes in angular 8.
change polyfills.ts and tsconfig.json .
Add a new file called tsconfig-es5.json with below content..

```
{
 "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
 "compilerOptions": {
 "target": "es5" 
 }
 }
```

change the target in tsconfig.json as 
    "target": "es5",

execute the following command  "ng serve"

Comment: This solution is not working for me. getting "Invalid character" from vendor.js in IE11 browser console. have tried all the solutions that are in this page. struggling from 3 days. any help would be much appreciated. for more about issue description and project details stackoverflow.com/questions/64386606/

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Un-comment plyfills in polyfills.ts. Also run all npm install commands mentionedin in polyfills.ts file to install those packages

Step 2:
In browserslist file remove not where IE 9-11 support is mentioned

Step 3:
In tsconfig.json file change like "target": "es2015" to "target": "es5"

These steps fixed my issue

Answer (score -3):

What about updating the included `browserslist` and remove the `not` before the `IE 9-11 ...? like this?

This file is used by the build system to adjust CSS and JS output to support the specified browsers below.
For additional information regarding the format and rule options, please see:
https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#queries

You can see what browsers were selected by your queries by running:

```
npx browserslist
```

> 0.5%
>   last 2 versions
>   Firefox ESR
>   not dead
>   IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.