# Angular 8 not working in IE 11 and Safari browser

Tags: angular

When I created sample application in Anuglar 8 and trying to run in IE 11 but not supporting. Tried different solutions which already provided in below link but still problem exists.

[How do I support Internet Explorer in an Angular 8 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56379067/how-do-i-support-internet-explorer-in-an-angular-8-application)

What else do I need to do? other then the above link?

Answer (score 3):

All you really need to do is change the `compilerOptions` target from `es2015` to `es5`.

If you don't really need the additional build configurations from the link you provided. Just modify the `tsconfig.json` (The one at the root of your project).

Should work after that, I just tested on a new project.

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "target": "es5",
    ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `TypeError: Result of expression 'jsonpArray.push.bind' [undefined] is not a function` I have done as u said and I have such error in safari