# angular8 Application not working in IE11 after updating from angular7

Tags: angular

I updated my angular app from 7.2 to 8.3. When I open the application in IE11 it showing only a blank screen. I tried by changing the target in tsconfig.json to 'es5' by replacing 'es2015' and also add old browser polyfills into the polyfills.ts file.But these are not fixed my issue.it still showing blank screen but works fine in chrome. How can I solve this issue?

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "src",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "allowJs": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es2017",
            "dom"
        ],
        "paths": {
            "@core/*": [
                "app/core/*"
            ],
            "@shared/*": [
                "app/shared/*"
            ],
            "@globals/*": [
                "app/globals/*"
            ],
            "@assets/*": [
                "assets/*"
            ],
            "@environments/*": [
                "environments/*"
            ],
            "@webcast/*": [
                "app/webcast/*"
            ]
        },
        "module": "esnext"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56379067/how-do-i-support-internet-explorer-in-an-angular-8-application

Comment: @KasabuckiAlexandr, I tried all the steps mentioned in that page.But none of them worked for me.

Comment: Do you happen to have any errors in your console? If so, please share them.
Furthermore, it would be very useful if you can share the `tsconfig.json` or other files that may interfere with your compilation process.

Comment: @PhilippMeissner, I edited the question with tsconfig.json, please check it.