# angular 8 application not working on IE 11

Tags: typescript, console, internet-explorer-11, angular8

I am working on Angular 8.

I have observed some problems with Internet Explorer version 11.

I am not able to perform any feature of my application when I close the console or inspect element.

when I load my application IE11 then if I inspect element and goto the console then I am able to perform my application features (my application has some features like creation of the topics, deletion of the topics, etc) but when I close the inspect element or console I am not able to perform any feature.

I did some R & D on the internet and updated my source code with some libraries that are required for the IE11 version (like classlist etc).

some of them are mentioned below.

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/promise';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

can anyone suggest me where I am doing something wrong?

Comment: When say not working.. are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Dalorzo no error.

Comment: Whether you have add some debugger in your code? Please check your code and try to remove it. Then, try to clear the browser data or restart the IE browser. Besides, I suggest you could refer to the [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56379067/how-do-i-support-internet-explorer-in-an-angular-8-application) to configure your angular application using  ES5.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT Yes I have checked all the things but only on the IE11 it is not working on the chrome it is working.

Comment: Can you create a [stackblitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/) to reproduce the problem? I have tested one angular sample on my side, it works well.