# Angular 8 is not loading in IE 11 Browser

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, browser, angular8

It is a duplicate question from [How do I support Internet Explorer in an Angular 8 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56379067/how-do-i-support-internet-explorer-in-an-angular-8-application) But I really wondering why none of the solution is not working for me including nested forum sites solutions too.Here are my snippets FYI.have tried a lot and being spending two days for this before posting here. curious to know what i missed and what will be the solution. much appreciated if get the expected solution.

**package.json**

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~8.0.3",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^8.0.0-beta.4",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^8.0.0-beta.4",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.3",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "highcharts": "^8.0.4",
    "highcharts-angular": "^2.4.0",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.4.6",
    "roboto-fontface": "^0.10.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.22",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.0.3",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^8.3.4",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^8.3.4",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^14.10.2",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-marbles": "^0.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "pretty-quick": "^2.0.1",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "sonarqube-scanner": "^2.5.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3",
    "yorkie": "^2.0.0",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.1",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32"
}
```

**index.html**

```
 <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script src="runtime-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="runtime-es5.js" nomodule></script>
    <script src="polyfills-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule></script>
    <script src="styles-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="styles-es5.js" nomodule></script>
    <script src="vendor-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="vendor-es5.js" nomodule></script>
    <script src="main-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="main-es5.js" nomodule></script>
</body>
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
"compileOnSave": false,
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext", 
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
```

**tsconfig-es5.app.json**

```
    {
    "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5"
    }
}
```

**angular.json**

```
  "build": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
  "options": {
      ...
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
        ...
    },
    "es5": {
      "tsConfig": "./tsconfig-es5.app.json"
    }
  }
},
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "options": {
      ...
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
     ...
    },
    "es5": {
      "browserTarget": "<app-name>:build:es5"
    }
  }
},
```

**browserlist**

```
# This file is used by the build system to adjust CSS and JS output to support the specified browsers below.
# For additional information regarding the format and rule options, please see:
# https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#queries

# You can see what browsers were selected by your queries by running:
#   npx browserslist

> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.
```

**polyfills.ts**

```
import 'classlist.js';
import 'core-js/es/array';
import 'core-js/es/date';
import 'core-js/es/function';
import 'core-js/es/map';
import 'core-js/es/math';
import 'core-js/es/number';
import 'core-js/es/object';
import 'core-js/es/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es/reflect';
import 'core-js/es/regexp';
import 'core-js/es/set';
import 'core-js/es/string';
import 'core-js/es/symbol';
import 'core-js/es/weak-map';
import 'web-animations-js';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

Here are referred sites including angular docs.please do not suggest the same again. expecting beyond all.

```
https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browserslistrc
https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#polyfills
https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2019/01/31/angular-cli-7.3/
https://karthiktechblog.com/angular/how-to-fix-your-angular-app-to-make-it-work-in-ie11
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14455
https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-fix-your-angular-app-when-its-not-working-in-ie11-eb24cb6d9920
https://dev.to/paulinhapenedo/angular-8-and-ie-11-1ed2
https://www.blexin.com/en-US/Article/Blog/How-to-support-Internet-Explorer-in-Angular-8-49
```

Comment: May this helps: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56379067/how-do-i-support-internet-explorer-in-an-angular-8-application) think this is exactly what your looking for

Comment: @Tom, Please see my question description that i already mentioned its duplicated from there. could you check my all code instead of checking my question title.?

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console? Is it an empty new site or you have implemented some functionality in it? If you have implemented some functionality then please provide information about it. I suggest you try to create a new app just for testing purposes. Open the `tsconfig.json` file and set `"target": "es5",`. Again try to run the app with the IE browser. You can try to provide more information about your app that may help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, am getting blank page with no error in console, and also am able to run the new and other angular application.

Comment: The issue may be related to the functionalities that you had added to this project. Try to check whether the libraries and the code you are using is supported in the IE browser and you have added the necessary polyfills. You also may need to transpile some code from ES6 to ES5 to make it work in the IE browser.