# How to serve Angular 7 application in IE11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, internet-explorer-11, ecmascript-5

I have updated my **pollyfills.ts** with below changes

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
 import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.


/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
```

I have updated **'target':'es5'** in **tsconfig.json**,

please let me know where and what I am missing.

Comment: What error you've got in IE11?

Comment: Actually there it not error message, but yes it is not loading an application. It just showing default IE error page with contents "There is an problem in loading this web page"

Comment: And there is no error or warning in console?

Comment: Yes there is no error or warning on console

Comment: I suggest you try to create a new Angular 7 project and try to refer to the steps mentioned in the answer to this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55647043/angular-7-project-is-not-working-in-internet-explorer-11 If possible for you then you can upgrade to Angular 8 and then try to refer to the steps in this link. https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-fix-your-angular-app-when-its-not-working-in-ie11-eb24cb6d9920 You can try to test and let us know about your testing results. If needed, we will try to provide further suggestions.